# Sum of reciprocal of curvatures of a curve of constant width and its opposite is constant

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, curvature, plane-curves, frenet-frame

The question I am trying to answer states that: Given a curve $\alpha (s)$ of constant width $R$, then $\beta (s) = \alpha (s) + R \mathbf{n}(s)$ is its opposite. Show that, $$\frac{1}{\kappa_\alpha}+\frac{1}{\kappa_\beta}$$ is a constant.

I have shown in a previous part of the question that for a parallel curve $\beta (s) = \alpha (s) -r \mathbf{n}(s)$, we have $\kappa_\beta=\frac{\kappa_\alpha}{1+r\kappa_\alpha}$.

So I took $r=-R$ in this formula, then attempted to show that $$(\frac{1}{\kappa_\alpha}+\frac{1}{\kappa_\beta})'=-\frac{\kappa'_\alpha}{\kappa_\alpha^2}-\frac{\kappa'_\beta}{\kappa_\beta^2}=0$$ which would imply that $\frac{1}{\kappa_\alpha}+\frac{1}{\kappa_\beta}$ is indeed constant.

However, I have found that $\kappa'_\beta=\frac{\kappa'_\alpha}{(1-R\kappa_\alpha)^2}$ and so $\frac{\kappa'_\beta}{\kappa_\beta^2}=\frac{\kappa'_\alpha}{\kappa_\alpha^2}$ which clearly doesn't give the desired result.

Any help to point me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Don’t do derivatives, since you know nothing about the derivative if curvature. Just do it algebraically, but you can't just substitute in your parallel curve formula. Note that in this case, the opposite curve is “anti-parallel” — compare the Frenet frames.

Comment: @ Sean O:  Is  $ \mathbf{n}(s)$ the bi-normal?